# CMake: Replace compile flags of an INTERFACE target

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I need to replace the `/std:c++14` flag of an `INTERFACE` target (header-only library) with `/std:c++17`. CMake doesn't support setting C++17 flags in VS directly yet (see [How to enable /std:c++17 in VS2017 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960715/how-to-enable-stdc17-in-vs2017-with-cmake)) so I need to manually replace it.

However `get_target_property(my_compile_flags mylib COMPILE_OPTIONS)` to retrieve the list of currently set flags to then subsequently replace /std:c++14 with /std:c++17 doesn't work:

> INTERFACE_LIBRARY targets may only have whitelisted properties.  The property "COMPILE_OPTIONS" is not allowed.

You can set them however via `target_compile_features(...)` and manually via e.g. `target_compile_options(mylib INTERFACE /std:c++17)`. But the latter command **adds** the flag, without removing `/std:c++14`.

How to go about that?

Comment: related, but not sure yet if any duplicatry going on: [How can I overwrite interface compile options coming from a linked library in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75599736/11107541)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an interface library you need to change [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) instead of [`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) (see [`add_library(INTERFACE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries)).

Here is a full example I've tested with VS2017 (using `/std:c++latest` since not yet supported `/std:c++17` may be ignored/removed by CMake):

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(InterfaceLibCppStd)

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

file(WRITE "mylib/Definitions.h" [=[ 
    #define HELLO_TEXT "Hello Interface Lib"
]=])
add_library(mylib INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(mylib INTERFACE "mylib")
target_compile_options(mylib INTERFACE "/std:c++14")

file(WRITE "main.cpp" [=[
    #include "Definitions.h"
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << HELLO_TEXT << std::endl;
    }
]=])
add_executable(myexe "main.cpp")

if (MSVC_VERSION GREATER_EQUAL "1900")
    CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("/std:c++latest" _cpp_latest_flag_supported)
    if (_cpp_latest_flag_supported)
        get_target_property(_opt_old mylib INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS)
        string(REPLACE "14" "latest" _opt_new "${_opt_old}")
        set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${_opt_new}")
   endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(myexe PUBLIC mylib)
```

Comment: @Ela782 Thanks :-) And you're welcome. Just it would be nice - to help us/me while answering -  if you could please add a [mcve] in future questions as a test case.

Comment: why does the answer say to change `INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` but go on to not touch `INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`? or am I just missing it?