# How to pass `-lstdc++` and `-static-libstdc++` without dynamically linking libstdc++?

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have a dependency that defines a CMake target with a public link option `-lstdc++` so that it can be linked into C programs. My C++ program depends on it. When I pass `-static-libstdc++`, GCC still links dynamically to libstdc++, which is not what I want. When I remove `-lstdc++` from the dependency options, it statically links to libstdc++, which is what I want. Is there a way to get GCC to statically link libstdc++ without changing the link options of my dependency (and without affecting other links, like `-static` does)?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way. Complain to the authors of your dependency.

Comment: This might be a case of [How can I overwrite interface compile options coming from an linked library in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75599736/11107541). Can you try my answer from over there and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: actually maybe not, since this is about link options, and the one I linked to is about compile options.