# Enabling support for C++17 in CMake for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I have a simple CMake (3.9.4) project with 3 libraries.

Basic library is an INTERFACE one (header only). It's using some features from C++17 that are present in Visual Studio (like constexpr if). Obviously I try to set a target property so that it propagated to dependent libraries.

I've tried:

```
target_compile_features(my_lib INTERFACE cxx_std_17)
```

But nothing changed.

Second attempt was:

```
set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERITES CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

But I get:

```
CMake Error at cpp/CMakeLists.txt:20 (set_target_properties):
INTERFACE_LIBRARY targets may only have whitelisted properties.  The
property "CXX_STANDARD" is not allowed.
```

Finally I ended up with:

```
target_compile_options(bit INTERFACE /std:c++17)
```

which works fine. Is this a correct solution? Taking a look at all the compile features I believe there should be something better I can do. Also that forces me to wrap the above command in some kind of `if(MSVC) ... endif()` shenanigans.

Comment: Please include the error you get with the second attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable /std:c++17 in VS2017 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960715/how-to-enable-stdc17-in-vs2017-with-cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake versions higher than 3.10 [support MSVC C++ standard switches](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16482), but on earlier versions they have no effect.

The only portable approach, to ensuring your program is compiled with the correct C++ standard mode on Visual Studio, is to require at least CMake 3.10, set the target property [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) to your desired value and [`CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html) to `ON`.

Example usage:

```
set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

<sub>Note: Currently `CXX_STANDARD` documentation for CMake 3.10 incorrectly states that it has no effect on MSVC. There's an issue tracking this [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17380).</sub>